# Не получается разделить button на части, где у каждой кнопки будет свой disable state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть `.map` в котором создаются несколько `<button>`, в зависимости от количества элементов:

```js
                     <td className="text-bottom">
                      <button
                        className="btn btn-w-icon delete-item"
                        title={label.title.delete}
                        disabled={isEdit}
                        onClick={() => {
                          this.handleDelete(
                            this.state.attribute.value,
                            sprNotDeleted
                          );
                        }}
                      />
                    </td>
```

Также, есть `<input>`, собственно на который ивент `disabled` реагирует по `setState`:

```js
            <td>
                    <input
                      type="email"
                      className="form-control"
                      value={sprNotDeleted.value}
                      onKeyDown={this.AttributeValidation}
                      onChange={this.inputChanged.bind(
                        this,
                        sprNotDeleted.id
                      )}
                    />
                  </td>
```

**inputChanged():**

```js
  inputChanged = (index, e) => {
    const { sprNotDeleted } = this.state;
    sprNotDeleted.forEach(point => {
      point.value = point.id === index ? e.target.value : point.value;
    });
    this.setState({ sprNotDeleted, isEdit: false });
  };
```

**AttributeValidation():**

```js
AttributeValidation = e => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    if (value === "") {
      this.setState({ isEdit: true });
    }
  };
```

Проблема в том, что сразу все кнопки становятся `disabled`, если я пишу !специально! неправильные значения для проверки. Нужно чтобы `disabled` становилась только та кнопка, к которой относится `input`. Плиз хелп.
Скриншот:[image: в примере видно что все кнопки становятся неактивны, но только 6 input редактируется с пустыми данными.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно вынести в отдельный компонент ваш инпут с кнопкой и сделать там локальный стейт на дизэйбл кнопки. Стейт инпутов можно хранить в родительском компоненте. Я в вашей логике не разбирался, но вот простой код, который дизэйблид кнопку при изменении инпута:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(["", "", ""]);
  function handleChange(value, i) {
    setValues(prev => prev.map((v, k) => (k === i ? value : v)));
  }
  return (
    <table>
      {values.map((value, i) => (
        <Row key={i} value={value} callback={value => handleChange(value, i)} />
      ))}
    </table>
  );
}

const Row = ({ value, callback }) => {
  const [isEdit, setIsEdit] = useState(false);
  function handleChange({ target: { value } }) {
    setIsEdit(true);
    callback(value);
  }
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
      </td>
      <td>
        <button disabled={isEdit}>button</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit gallant-sun-6oggn]